# Reading cross domain cookie

Tags: java, javascript, jsf-2

Can javascript/JSF read a cookie from a different domain?

If i set a cookie in one domain say www.domain1.com. Can i read that cookie from a different domain www.domain2.com?

If yes, how?

I have tried below code but its not reading cookie value from mentioned URL i.e. http://host.example.com

```
public void getCookieUsingCookieHandler() { 
try {       
    // Instantiate CookieManager;
    // make sure to set CookiePolicy
    CookieManager manager = new CookieManager();
    manager.setCookiePolicy(CookiePolicy.ACCEPT_ALL);
    CookieHandler.setDefault(manager);

    // get content from URLConnection;
    // cookies are set by web site
    URL url = new URL("http://host.example.com");
    URLConnection connection = url.openConnection();
    connection.getContent();

    // get cookies from underlying
    // CookieStore
    CookieStore cookieJar =  manager.getCookieStore();
    List <HttpCookie> cookies =
        cookieJar.getCookies();
    for (HttpCookie cookie: cookies) {
      System.out.println("CookieHandler retrieved cookie: " + cookie);
    }
} catch(Exception e) {
    System.out.println("Unable to get cookie using CookieHandler");
    e.printStackTrace();
}
```

}

Comment: Does that seem secure to you? Do you want them reading your email/bank's cookies? Your code would be reading cookies from the server session and not the clients.

Comment: Yes. Reading cookie from another domain is secure for me.

Answer (score 2):

This is completely insecure and not possible.  epascarello hit it on the head.  If you can read cookies from any domain, then you would be able to steal session cookies from users who just happened to open your web page.

Comment: Is there any other way I can just verify if the cookie has been set in another domain?

Comment: No.  There is one caveat... it is possible to share cookies across subdomains of the same domain.  For instance com.yoursite.domain1 can scope cookies to com.yoursite and then com.yoursite.domain2 can access those cookies and vice versa.